# MySql Select rows with 30 minutes difference in date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MySql-8.0/MariaDb-10.4 table that contains a list of site visits of different visitors:

[image]

I want to create a query that returns the **first** visit of **each visit session**, where the session definition is where the `CreatedAt` date is 30 min or more from the previous visits.

So in my case, I should be returning row 2 (Id column), row 8 and row 13. Note also that a session can be more than 30 minutes, as long as each visit succeeds a previous visit with less than 30min.

My solution was as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.`CreatedAt`
    FROM  activities AS a
    LEFT JOIN  activities AS b
    ON ( 
        (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(b.`CreatedAt`)  >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.`CreatedAt`) - (30 * 60)) ) AND 
        (b.`CreatedAt` < a.`CreatedAt`)
    )
    WHERE (b.`CreatedAt` IS NULL) AND (a.`VisitorId` = '26924c19-3cd1-411e-a771-5ebd6806fb27' /* or others for example */ )
```

It works alright, but it does not return the last row 13, also I'm not sure it's the best solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to approach this is to relate all visits to their **earlier** siblings and then chose only those, that have none. The (more intuitive) other approach of taking the fist of each, that has a **later** sibling will fail if no later visit exists (as in your example with ID 13).

```
SELECT
  late.*
FROM activities AS late
LEFT JOIN activities AS early
  ON late.VisitorId=early.VisitorId
  AND late.CreatedAt>early.CreatedAt
  AND late.CreatedAt<=DATE_ADD(early.CreatedAt, INTERVAL +30 MINUTE)
WHERE early.Id IS NULL
-- Maybe: AND late.VisitorId='26924c19-3cd1-411e-a771-5ebd6806fb27'
-- Maybe: ORDER BY late.CreatedAt
```

Comment: what if i want to build the query so it returns the *last* visit of each visit session, instead of the first, so row 12 would be returned for the session (8,9,10,11,12)

Comment: This would again create the situation you were in: At any point in time it is unknown, if a current session is still in progress or already ended. The DB of past events can't look into the future. You can though try to self-join to find the last visit to each session selected by the given query.

Comment: the lead window function turned out to be very useful in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443546/mysql-select-last-row-with-30-minutes-difference-in-date

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar answer to @Eugen Rieck https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027502/625144. But using `MySQL` `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function

```
SELECT a.*, 
FROM activities a
LEFT JOIN activities b
    ON b.VisitorId = a.VisitorId
        AND a.Id > b.Id
        AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, b.CreatedAt, a.CreatedAt) <= 30
WHERE
    b.Id IS NULL
;
```