# MySql Select last row with 30 minutes difference in date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is a followup to this question [MySql Select rows with 30 minutes difference in date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027369/mysql-select-rows-with-30-minutes-difference-in-date), albeit similar in concept the solution needed might be different.

I have a MySql-8.0/MariaDb-10.4 table that contains a list of site visits of different visitors:

[image]

I want to create a query that returns the **last** visit of **each visit session**, where the session definition is where the `CreatedAt` date is 30 min or more from the previous visits.

So in my case, I should be returning row 7 (Id column), row 12 and row 13. Note also that a session can be more than 30 minutes, as long as each visit succeeds a previous visit with less than 30min.

The neat solution suggest by @EugenRieck was as follows:

```
SELECT
  late.*
FROM activities AS late
LEFT JOIN activities AS early
  ON late.VisitorId=early.VisitorId
  AND late.CreatedAt>early.CreatedAt
  AND late.CreatedAt<=DATE_ADD(early.CreatedAt, INTERVAL +30 MINUTE)
WHERE early.Id IS NULL
-- Maybe: AND late.VisitorId='26924c19-3cd1-411e-a771-5ebd6806fb27'
-- Maybe: ORDER BY late.CreatedAt
```

It works great, but it works by returning the **first visit** in each visit session, not the **last visit**. I tried to modify to work as i wanted but with no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of gap-and-islands problem.  But you can handle it using `lead()`.  Just check if the next `createdAt` is over 30 minutes from the value in a given row.  That is the last row for a session:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lead(createdAt) over (partition by visitorid order by createdat) as next_ca
      from activities a
     ) a
where next_ca > createdAt + interval 30 minute;
```

Usually, in this situation you would want the last row as well.  You would get that with `or next_ca is null`.

Comment: great stuff, never knew the lead function existed in the first place, thanks